# Is there any difference between Bounded and Totally bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

> Is there any difference between bounded and totally bounded? (in a metric space)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The real line $\Bbb R$ endowed with the metric $d(x,y)=\min(1,|x-y|)$ is a bounded metric space that isn't totally bounded.

Answer (score 10):

Just to throw one more answer into the mix, any infinite set with the discrete metric is bounded but not totally bounded (I like @Gedgar's answer better, but just for some variety...)

Answer (score 7):

A major theorem in metric space theory is that a metric space is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded. In $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with the usual metric ( for $n < \infty$), bounded and totally bounded are the same, which is essentially the content of the Heine Borel theorem. In fact, the unit ball of a Banach space is compact if and only if the space is finite dimensional.

Answer (score 4):

Every totally bounded set is bounded.  But not conversely.  The unit ball in Hilbert space is bounded, but not totally bounded.

Comment: Maybe you mean an infinite dimensional Hilbert space?